# SSH public key authentication doesn't work only on special user

Tags: authentication, ssh, centos, barman

I'm having trouble setting up public key authentication for an SSH server on CentOS 6.8. What is strange is that when I login with a postgres user it goes well, but when I login with the 'barman' user which is created automatically by installing barman it always needs password.

The 'postgres' user's home directory and the barman user's home directory are in the same folder. I think the problem has nothing to do with the sshd config, tried to set the barman's home path, the .ssh path and the authorized_keys's permission all the same as postgres. But it still doesn't work .
This is what I get after run `ssh localhost -vvv`:

```
    OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: Applying options for *
    debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
    debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /var/lib/barman/.ssh/id_rsa.
    debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
    debug3: key_read: missing keytype
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
    debug3: key_read: missing keytype
    debug1: identity file /var/lib/barman/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
    debug1: identity file /var/lib/barman/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version                 OpenSSH_5.3
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
    debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug3: Wrote 960 bytes for a total of 981
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-        sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-        cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-        ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-        sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
    debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
    debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
    debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
    debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 1005
    debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 139/256
    debug2: bits set: 514/1024
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
    debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 1149
    debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host localhost filename /var/lib/barman/.ssh/known_hosts
    debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host localhost filename /var/lib/barman/.ssh/known_hosts
    debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
    debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /var/lib/barman/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug2: bits set: 523/1024
    debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
    debug2: kex_derive_keys
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 1165
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    debug3: Wrote 48 bytes for a total of 1213
    debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug2: key: /var/lib/barman/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f6ef1fcc740)
    debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 1277
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
    debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
    debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
    debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
    debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
    debug1: No valid Key exchange context
    debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
    debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
    debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
    debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
    debug3: Trying to reverse map address ::1.
    debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
    Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_498' not found

    debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
    Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_498' not found

    debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


    debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
    Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_498' not found

    debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
    debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
    debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering public key: /var/lib/barman/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug3: send_pubkey_test
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1645
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
    debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
    debug3: authmethod_lookup password
    debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
    debug1: Next authentication method: password
    barman@localhost's password:
```

Comment: Probably has something to do with strict mode. If the folders above `barman` are group/world accessible, sshd might not like it.

Comment: Barman and postgres are located in the same folder, but postgres doesn't have such a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authorized_keys file that is inside the user’s home directory has the wrong context. In this example, the context of the file is “unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0”. The context sshd is running in does not have access to this context, resulting in SELinux denying access to the file. With no access to the file, the key authentication fails.
run the following command to reset it:

```
chcon -R unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 /path/to/users/homedirectory/.ssh/
```